# Html5 canvas font weight is rendering much heavier than it should

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fonts

I'm new to html5 canvas and I've run into a problem trying to render text. I have set in my code that the text should render in Gotham at a 'regular' weight but it seems to be rendering in bold or even heavier. I've attached a snippet of the code and two screenshots of how the heavy the weight should be and how heavy it is in canvas for comparison.

```
ctxt.textAlign = "left";
ctxt.font = "Regular 34px Gotham, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif";
ctxt.fillStyle = "#fff";
```

[What the font weight should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcJrg.png)

[What the font weight is rendered as in canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OQJv.png)

Answer (score 4):

The HTML canvas font property includes a lot of attributes at once. `Regular` is no valid value for any of them. Use e.g. `normal` or `lighter` to set the font-weight. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font) or this example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "normal 30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 20, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first property in the font string is style, which can be one of normal, oblique or italic. the second property is weight, which can be normal (but not Regular).

```
ctxt.font = "normal 34px Gotham, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif";
```

Should work.